# Convert strings to RegexOptions and pass to Regex constructor

Tags: c#, regex

I have a .NET winform with a list of selectable (multi-select) `RegexOptions` that the user can select zero, one, or multiple of. Also they can specify a regex pattern and test a string. So I create my `Regex` object without options so far:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
```

This all works fine and my regex pattern testing against a test value works fine. But I can't figure out how to convert selected regex option strings to the RegexOptions enum, then pass into the constructor for Regex. The traditional way it would be instantiated is this (as one example):

```
new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

So if the user chooses the strings "Compiled" and "IgnoreCase" from the listbox, how do I transform those strings into the enum values `RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` and hand into the Regex constructor?

Comment: Just use a dictionary with string keys and RegexOptions values as values. Then `|` them (if multiple are selected).

Comment: @HerrimanCoder that sounds like a bad idea to be honest, I'd listen to Wiktor, that sounds much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can either pass it each string separately and `|=` them together, or you can actually pass a comma separated list and do it in one go.

So something like:

```
var options = (RegexOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegexOptions), "Compiled");
options |= (RegexOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegexOptions), "IgnoreCase");
```

Or (better):

```
var options = (RegexOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegexOptions), "Compiled,IgnoreCase");
```

The better solution would be to have list box bound to the values of the enum and display the string values and then you could get them without parsing.

Comment: Works great! Thank you Matt.